# What is the command to execute command line arguments with NGINX Ingress Controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I feel like I'm missing something pretty basic here, but can't find what I'm looking for.

Referring to the NGINX Ingress Controller documentation regarding [command line arguments](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/cli-arguments/) how exactly would you use these? Are you calling a command on the nginx-ingress-controller pod with these arguments? If so, what is the command name?

Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line arguments are accepted by the Ingress controller executable.This can be set in container spec of the `nginx-ingress-controller` Deployment manifest.

List of annotation document :

> https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md

Command line argument document:

> https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/cli-arguments.md

If you will run the command

> kubectl describe deployment/nginx-ingress-controller --namespace

You will find this snip :

```
Args:
  --default-backend-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-http-backend
  --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-services
  --annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io
```

Where these all are command line arguments of nginx as suggested.From here you can also change the `--annotations-prefix=nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io` from here.

Default annotation in nginx is `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io`.

`!!! note` The annotation prefix can be changed using the `--annotations-prefix` inside [command line argument](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/cli-arguments.md), but the default is `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io`.

Comment: I followed this answer and I found that the deployment is inside this file:
`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml'. I just want to share that as there may be people like me who would like to automate the change.

Comment: didn't get that. you want to automate the deployment of ingress-nginx-controller ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [the Helm chart](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-deployment.yaml#L90), then you can simply create a configmap named `{{ include "ingress-nginx.fullname" . }}-tcp` in the same namespace where the ingress controller is deployed. (Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out what the default value is for `ingress-nginx.fullname`... sorry. If someone knows, feel free to edit this answer.)

If you need to specify a different namespace for the configmap, then you might be able to use the [`.Values.tcp.configMapNamespace` property](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/charts/ingress-nginx/values.yaml#L130), but honestly, I wasn't able to find it applied anywhere in the code, so YMMV.

```
  ## Allows customization of the tcp-services-configmap
  ##
  tcp:
    configMapNamespace: ""   # defaults to .Release.Namespace
    ## Annotations to be added to the tcp config configmap
    annotations: {}
```